# How can I change cols of textarea in twitter-bootstrap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

If I change the value of :rows, it works. But it stays at the default cols whatever value I set with ':cols =>'. Column width won't change.

I viewed the html source and it reflected the change. I wonder that bootstrap's CSS might be the suspect...

HTML (there is a "cols=" in the final HTML, but column width stays at the default value, which is 30. I can't believe my eyes!)

```
<textarea cols="100" id="comment_body" name="comment[body]" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Rails:

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <i class="icon-user"></i>
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <i class="icon-comment"></i>
    <%= f.text_area :body, :rows => 5, :cols => 100 %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  <div> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: i don't think you can actually set cols. try setting width instead

Comment: Thanks. You save me! I added :style => "width:380px;" and it works.

Comment: I think you can also use class="field span3" or span4 or whatever, in the text div

Comment: using inline CSS is not a good idea, you'll loose Bootstrap great benefit responsivity! instead you really should give class="field span3" as mentioned by @hagope because then it can be changed based on browser's width.

Comment: Thanks. I'll use class="field span3". You saved me.

Comment: wow i didn't know about span3 etc - thanks

Comment: i think width:100% also works ?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The other answers didn't work for me. This did:

```
    <div class="span6">
      <h2>Document</h2>
        </p>
        <textarea class="field span12" id="textarea" rows="6" placeholder="Enter a short synopsis"></textarea>
        <button class="btn">Upload</button>
    </div>
```

Note the `span12` in a div with `span6`.

Comment: I just put a `span12` to the textarea: `<textarea class="span12" rows="18"></textarea>`. The
`textarea` is in `html>body>form#aspnetForm>div.conainer`. Btw, I did not find class `field` in bootstrap v2.1.1

Comment: @Perry Horwich answer is better because it uses the html generated by the simple form/formatstic


f.input :some_text, :input_html => {:rows => 5, :placeholder => "Enter some text.", :class => "span6"}

Comment: This works, but I suspect @Yarx's answer below is "more" correct for the majority of situations.

Answer (score 54):

**UPDATE:** As of Bootstrap 3.0, the `input-*` classes described below for setting the width of input elements were removed. Instead use the `col-*` classes to set the width of input elements. [Examples are provided in the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes).

---

In Bootstrap 2.3, you'd use the input classes for setting the width.

```
<textarea class="input-mini"></textarea>
<textarea class="input-small"></textarea>
<textarea class="input-medium"></textarea>
<textarea class="input-large"></textarea>
<textarea class="input-xlarge"></textarea>
<textarea class="input-xxlarge"></textarea>​
<textarea class="input-block-level"></textarea>​
```

Do a find for "Control sizing" for [examples in the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms).

But for height I think you'd still use the rows attribute.

Comment: Note that VS 2013 has a specific max-width set to 280px in the site.css.   This effectively disables bootstraps col-* implementation.   To override the override for an individual element use style="max-width: none".  Using the inline style will allow col-* to set the width of the element to fit the column.

Comment: That's funny I actually came across this today. The 280px constraint is only on input fields though I believe. I just removed the constraint altogether. I'd rather rely on bootstrap to do this, as simply limiting it to 280px for input elements breaks other features of Bootstrap, like grouped inputs.

Comment: Greg, you're such a life saver! Have been banging my head at this since morning (pretty new to CSS)! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 17):

Simply add the bootstrap "row-fluid" class to the textarea. It will stretch to 100% width;

Update:
For bootstrap 3.x use "col-xs-12" class for textarea;

Update II:
Also if you want to extend the container to full width use: container-fluid class.

Comment: This is the best answer IMO. Using this in a modal box  (haml simple_form): `= f.input :body, label: 'Message', as: :text, input_html: {class: 'row-fluid', rows: '10'}`

Answer (score 14):

I found the following in the site.css generated by VS2013

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

To override this behavior in a specific element, add the following...

```
 style="max-width: none;"
```

For example:

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
      <textarea style="max-width: none;" 
                class="form-control" 
                placeholder="a col-md-6 multiline input box" />
 </div>
```

Comment: i have searched all over the web and this answer should get upvoted more

Comment: If you are using VS 2013 ...THIS IS THE ANSWER...please up vote this so future readers don't get lost by the old answer.   Also, if you want to override this behavior in a specific element, add the following.         style="max-width: none;"

Comment: Worked for me like a charm in VS 2015

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this is the correct way however I did this:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="id1">Label:</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <textarea id="id1" class="textareawidth" rows="10" name="anyname">value</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

and put this in my bootstrapcustom.css file:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .textareawidth {
        width:500px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .textareawidth {

    }
}
```

This way it resizes based on the viewport. Seems to line everything up nicely on a big browser and on a small mobile device.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me with twitter bootstrap 2 and simple_form 2.0.4
Result is a span6 text area in a span9 row

```
 <div class="row" >
   <div class="span9">
     <%= f.input :some_text, :input_html => {:rows => 5, :placeholder => "Enter some text.", :class => "span6"}%>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to split off the textarea in the Site.css as follows:

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */

input,
select {

  max-width: 280px;
}

textarea {

  /*max-width: 280px;*/
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 280px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

also (in my MVC 5) add ref to textarea:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => ................... @class = "form-control", @id="textarea"............
```

It worked for me