# Bootstrap text_area width under haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I have a Rails app and am using haml and bootstrap. One my form I have two fields for entering text, and only one is displayed, depending on a variable I set in the controller. If there is a text area I would like to size it, and the **:rows** attribute works but not columns.

I have also tried to use **%div :class => 'span6'** to widen the text_area, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
= form_for [@lesson_layout, @layout_field] do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :field_name
    = f.text_field :field_name
  - case @layout_type
  - when "Text Field"
    .field
      = f.label :field_value
      = f.text_field :field_value
    - when "Text Area"
      .field
        = f.label :field_value_long
        = f.text_area :field_value_long, :rows => 5, :placeholder => 'Enter text.'

.actions
  = f.submit
```

**EDIT**

Tried the following code, and it did not change the size of the box.

```
.field
  = f.label :field_value_long
  = f.text_area :field_value_long, :rows => 5, :placeholder => 'Enter text using markdown.', :html => { :style => "width:300em" }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133783/how-can-i-change-cols-of-textarea-in-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: I did look at that question. I may be having a problem with the haml syntax. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this should work :
`= f.text_area :field_value_long, :rows => 5, :class => "span6", :placeholder => 'Enter text.'`

Answer (score 1):

```
f.text_area( 
  :field_value_long, 
  :rows => 5, 
  :placeholder => 'Enter text.', 
  :html => { :style => "width:20em !important" }
)
```

OR

```
f.text_area( 
  :field_value_long, 
  :rows => 5, 
  :placeholder => 'Enter text.', 
  :html => { :class => "my_wide_class" }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. I tried the first one (see edit above), and it didn't like the () so I left them out and it rendered the page but the box didn't change size.